# How was this JSON string's unicode badly encoded, and how can I reverse it?

Tags: json, unicode

I'm pretty sure I have some double-encoding going on and I can't wrap my head around the actual route it was encoded with, or whether it's reversible.

My JSON file contains the string `"R\\u00c3\\u0083\\u00c2\\u00b6yksopp"`, which is SUPPOSED to be `Röyksopp`, but it renders as `RÃƒÂ¶yksopp`.

The UTF-8 HEX of `ö` is `0xC3 0xB6`, which happen to be the first and last of the four escaped characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you interpreted a UTF-8 string as Latin-1, then encoded that as UTF-8 and interpreted it as Latin-1 again, and encoded that to JSON. Here's a fix in Python:

```
>>>> s
'"R\\u00c3\\u0083\\u00c2\\u00b6yksopp"'
>>>> json.loads(s)
'RÃ\x83Â¶yksopp'
>>>> json.loads(s).encode('latin1')
b'R\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6yksopp'
>>>> json.loads(s).encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'RÃ¶yksopp'
>>>> json.loads(s).encode('latin1').decode('utf-8').encode('latin1')
b'R\xc3\xb6yksopp'
>>>> json.loads(s).encode('latin1').decode('utf-8').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'Röyksopp'
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That JSON must have gone through many Windows-based hands before it got to me.

Comment: @prooffreader it's probably the best if you fix the problem at the source, you never know how much encodings their next JSON will have

Comment: @Ferrybig oh definitely, I just needed to understand what was happening and provide a temp fix so I can bust some heads